# How to checkout (PayPal) in non USD currency?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a 1.9 store that uses multiple currencies, the problem: standard pp checkout still calculates everything in USD when user is redirected there.

How do I force paypal to checkout in the currency that the user has selected?

Try adding item like this after selecting currency other than USD and you will see https://www.airyhair.com/tape-in-hair-extensions.html

Googled for solutions but all appear to be for 1,7 or older versions of Magento

Comment: Isn't there also a setting in your PayPal Merchant account? I think you should also have a look there.

Comment: Can't see such setting, do you know where it is located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is no basic configuration for that : "If your store's base currency is USD, and your customer chooses EURO on your webpage, he/she will be confused at checkout. The reason is because on the paypal site your user will be presented a price in USD instead of EURO, which may make you lose the sale from confusion."
Source : https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/paypal-multi-currency.html
Other source : https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/25637/s/store-currency-payment-checkout/